# how add a column in dataframe after applying groupby

Tags: python, pandas

**I have dataframe like this**

```
    id             Date
    546451991   2018-07-31 00:00:00
    546451991   2018-08-02 00:00:00
    5441440119  2018-08-13 00:00:00
    5441440119  2018-08-13 00:00:00
    5441440119  2018-08-14 00:00:00
    5344265358  2018-07-13 00:00:00
    5344265358  2018-07-15 00:00:00
    5441438884  2018-07-19 00:00:00
```

**I want to groupby 'ID' then sort on the basis of date then add a column containing date of next ROW**

**E.g i want output like this**

```
 id             Date              Date1
546451991   2018-07-31 00:00:00  2018-08-02 00:00:00
546451991   2018-08-02 00:00:00  NULL
5441440119  2018-08-13 00:00:00  2018-08-14 00:00:00
5441440119  2018-08-14 00:00:00  2018-08-15 00:00:00
5441440119  2018-08-15 00:00:00  NULL
5344265358  2018-07-13 00:00:00  2018-07-15 00:00:00
5344265358  2018-07-15 00:00:00  NULL
5441438884  2018-07-19 00:00:00  NULL
```

**i have tried but not succeeded** 
 `df.groupby('id')['Date'].sort_values()` not working

Comment: I think you mean "next row" not "next column"?

Comment: You're not clear about what kind of sorting you would like to do in your df, is it ascending or descending?

Comment: Can you please post a pre-made DF? I'm faffing around now for quite a while trying to get this into a testable format from the clipboard, when I should be trying to answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Date1'] = df.groupby('id')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().shift(-1))
```

Out:

```
            Date           id          Date1
0   2018-07-3100:00:00  546451991   2018-08-0200:00:00
1   2018-08-0200:00:00  546451991   NaN
2   2018-08-1300:00:00  5441440119  2018-08-1300:00:00
3   2018-08-1300:00:00  5441440119  2018-08-1400:00:00
4   2018-08-1400:00:00  5441440119  NaN
5   2018-07-1300:00:00  5344265358  2018-07-1500:00:00
6   2018-07-1500:00:00  5344265358  NaN
7   2018-07-1900:00:00  5441438884  NaN
```

**edit**

from sandeep inputs

```
df['Date1'] = df.groupby('id')['Date'].shift(-1)
```

Comment: i tried your code but it is giving me following error

**TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index**

Comment: I checked the code again, it is giving the same results. are you using id as index as index ?

Comment: No but my index are not in increasing order values are missing 
e.g 1,2,4,7,8,9,10

Comment: please reset the index <b> df.reset_index(drop = True,inplace = True) </b>

Comment: Yes @SandeepKadapa, i didnt think of that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for, while @Naga Kiran's answer does it in one liner, I'm just making things simple step by step.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1, 2, 3, 4], "Date":["2018-07-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-09-02", "2018-10-03"]})
newdf = df.sort_values(["Date"], ascending=False)
newdf["Date1"] = newdf["Date"].transform(lambda x:x.shift(-1))
newdf.groupby("id").head(3)
```

I first sorted the dataframe, then added the Date1 with `shift(-1)` which shift the column value in one row up,  then did the `groupby("id")`.

Hope this helps.